# SQL left join takes too long

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime

I need to run a sql query that takes 24s. I tried to create indices on the two datetime columns START_DATE and END_DATE but my connection gets interupted after 600s. Is there any way to write a faster query?

```
SELECT tbl1.*,
         tbl2.NAME
         FROM (  SELECT * FROM table1
                WHERE LOC_ID IN (%s)
                AND START_DATE != END_DATE
                AND START_DATE <= '2002-01-31' 
                AND END_DATE >= '2002-01-01') tbl1
         LEFT JOIN 
            table2 as tbl2
                ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
```

EDIT:
I tried moving the where clause outside which increased the duration to 120 seconds.

I changed the query to the suggestion but it still takes the 24s, i gained a few ms only

Comment: The moment you use a function over the field, you cant use the index. your problem isnt the `LEFT JOIN` is the sub query

Comment: Some SQLs let you create indexes on functions of columns, such as YEAR(START_DATE).

Comment: @TobSta; instead of YEAR/MONTH <= and >=, use BETWEEN YEAR/MONTH (lowerbound) and YEAR/MONTH (upperbound)

Comment: Depending on your version of MySQL, your sub-query could be making it inefficient. It looks like you don't need the sub-query and you could do FROM table 1 LEFT JOIN table 2 and move your sub-query WHERE clause  to the outer query.

Comment: Hi. This is not the code you ran since you use tbl1 in a subselect where it is not defined. Anyway please read & act on [mcve]. For performance issues that includes EXPLAIN output. But you need to give exact DDL, DML & input & confirmed correct output. And your descriptions of what you tried & what happened are not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following would be synonymous to your current logic and wouldn't destroy the ability to use the index on your dates:

```
SELECT tbl1.*,
     tbl2.NAME
FROM table1 tbl1
     LEFT JOIN table2 as tbl2
        ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID
WHERE tbl1.LOC_ID IN (%s)
     AND tbl1.START_DATE <> tbl1.END_DATE
     AND tbl1.START_DATE <= '2002-01-31' 
     AND tbl1.END_DATE >= '2002-01-01';
```

Even without an index, I suspect this, or the subquery form of this, would be quicker since the CPU doesn't have to split the dateparts for your two fields on EVERY record in the table to perform the comparison.

Comment: For some reason that returns more rows than the original query, but it should be synonymous to my logic. There's no change in the execution duration though.

Comment: That's curious that you didn't get a bump in speed removing the functions from the WHERE clause. I suspect those functions are highly tuned, but it's still an extra trip round the CPU that we are removing. I think the real trick is getting an index on those date fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *, 
        ( SELECT  NAME
            FROM  table2
            WHERE  ID = table1.id 
        ) AS NAME
    FROM  table1
    WHERE  LOC_ID IN (%s)
      AND  START_DATE != END_DATE
      AND  START_DATE <= '2002-01-31'
      AND  END_DATE   >= '2002-01-01';
```

With these indexes:

```
INDEX(START_DATE),
INDEX(END_DATE),
INDEX(LOC_ID, START_DATE),
INDEX(LOC_ID, END_DATE)
```

The date range you have is essentially impossible to optimize; having multiple indexes gives the Optimizer a choice; it will pick from them based on the distribution of the data.  That is, changing the month in question may lead to using a different index.

The indexes starting with `LOC_ID` are an optimization for (1) a single LOC being used, or (2) LOC does a better job of filtering than either date.

The subquery will fail if the relationship is 1:many; I am guessing that it is 1:1.  Why have table2?  Usually (not always) it is unwise to have two tables in a 1:1 relationship.

Don't use `SELECT *` unless you really need all the columns.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and how many rows are in the table.

What version of MySQL?  (Newer versions will perform this query better.)